# Write special chars in hardstatus of GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I want write the next specials chars to hardstatus of GNU Screen: "↑" (*up arrow*) and "↓" (*down arrow*), but it shows strange chars.
How can I do this?

**More info**:
This worked to me before but I have to reinstall my SO (Ubuntu 11.04) and now it doesn't work.

My .screenrc:

```
startup_message off
vbell off
deflogin off
shell bash

bindkey -k k1 detach

termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
backtick 25 1 1 $HOME/bin/scripts_screen/velocidad_eth1
backtick 26 300 300 $HOME/bin/scripts_screen/espacio_libre_servidor
backtick 27 300 300 $HOME/bin/scripts_screen/espacio_libre_menor_que
hardstatus alwayslastline "  %{= Wb}%LD %d %LM, %c %{=b Wk}| %?%{=b rg}%27`%:%{= Wm}%?Espacio libre: %26` %{=b Wk}| %{= Wk}%25`"
```

I think this problem is related to enconding but my locales are correct:

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is a capture of a screen session:
[image: capture of screen session]

You can see that the unicode characters in terminal are correct but not the unicode chars of hardstatus/caption screen.

Comment: Can't you use ^ and v? AFAIK, Screen doesn't support Unicode.

Comment: It supports, but I don't remember how.
I used this characters before reinstalling my system without problems but now it doesn't work.

Comment: I've added more info in main post.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of screen is earlier than 4.1.x, then it's a known bug. See: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/?id=28c161010579e59ae5d310db277f8978911ac794